# How can I get a video thumbnail from a local video in the raw-folder to show in an ImageView?

Tags: android, thumbnails

I'm trying to create a thumbnail from a video and place it in an ImageView in Android, but it doesn't work. I'm not sure if the file path I use is correct.

The code I'm using:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
String filepath = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.videotest;
Bitmap bm = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filepath, Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
```